# Off-canvas mini cart for Magento, please suggest

Tags: magento

I have a magento site from client required a mini cart. I do follow this tutorial but not success yet http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/mobile-off-canvas-mini-cart-2/

Please suggest me an extension, any free module as good.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is far too broad.  Can you edit it to make it clear what your requirements are?

Comment: Thanks #Tritim21 for your fast reply. I want to find a magento module for an off-canvas layout like the article. Im not expert in Magento so when I do follow their tutorial, it not work for me. The offcanvas module should replace the default dropdown cart of theme. We are using Ultimo Theme

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. It should be on http://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an extension with Off-canvas mini cart, Off-canvas Checkout, One step checkout.. All in one package
But it is not free :( (search with keyword Fancy Checkout)

Btw, Can you please post your custom module or reference code here, I would like to looking for same thing but free too.
Also let me know if you have solved your problem to make it work.

Comment: Thanks #Ben12 for your suggestion the http://fancycheckout.com. It look great but I will wating for a free module if someone has read the tutorial above